# How to find the Laurent series for $\frac1{\sin(z)}$ in the regions $0<|z|<\pi$ and $\pi<|z|<2\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, laurent-series, partial-fractions

I know that

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sin(z)}
&=\frac1z\frac{z}{\sin(z)}\\
&=\frac1z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\frac{z^6}{7!}+\cdots\right)^{-1}\\
&=\frac1z\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{7z^4}{360}+\frac{31z^6}{15120}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac1z+\frac{z}{6}+\frac{7z^3}{360}+\frac{31z^5}{15120}+\cdots
\end{align}
$$

but I am not sure how to continue to find the Laurent series for $\frac1{\sin(z)}$ in the regions $0<|z|<\pi$ and $\pi<|z|<2\pi$?

Comment: I guess you known where the simple poles of $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ lie and their residues, so you know the "singular part" in every annulus.

Answer (score 1):

In the Laurent series for $1/\sin(z)$ valid in $0<|z|<\pi$, the formula
for the coefficients involves Bernoulli numbers ([LINK](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Csc/06/01/02/01/0003/)).  The first few terms were found by the OP.
$$
\frac{1}{\sin z} = z^{-1}+\frac{z}{6}+\frac{7z^3}{360}+\frac{31z^5}{15120}+\cdots\qquad 0<|z|<\pi .
$$

---

What about $\pi < |z| < 2\pi$?  Jack D'Aurizio commented the method to use.

The residue of $1/\sin(z)$ at $z=\pi$ is $-1$.  So
$$
f_1(z) := \frac{1}{\sin z}+\frac{1}{z-\pi}
$$
is analytic in $0 < |z| < 2\pi$.  Its Laurent series, valid in $0<|z|<2\pi$
begins
$$
f_1(z) = z^{-1} - \frac{1}{\pi} + \left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{\pi^2}\right) z
-\frac{1}{\pi^3} z^2 + \cdots\qquad 0<|z|<2\pi .
\tag1$$
Now note that $1/\sin(z) = f_1(z)-f_2(z)$ where
$$
f_2(z) := \frac{1}{z-\pi}
$$
A geometric series, valid in $|z|>\pi$ is
$$
f_2(z) = z^{-1}+\pi z^{-2} + \pi^2 z^{-3} +\cdots\qquad |z|>\pi.
\tag2$$
So subtract using $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get the series valid in $\pi < |z| < 2\pi$.
$$
\frac{1}{\sin z} = \cdots + \pi^2 z^{-3} + \pi z^{-2}
- \frac{1}{\pi} + \left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{\pi^2}\right) z
-\frac{1}{\pi^3} z^2 + \cdots
\qquad \pi < |z| < 2\pi .
$$
It seems the $z^{-1}$ term is $0$.

Answer (score -1):

Since the power series for $\;\sin z\;$ around zero has infinite convergence radius we can use everywhere, thus: for $\;z\;$ close to zero, we have

$$\frac1{\sin z}=\frac1{z-\frac{z^3}6+\frac{z^5}{120}-\ldots}=\frac1{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+\mathcal O(z^4)\right)}\stackrel{\text{geometric series}}=$$

$$=\frac1z\left(1+\frac{z^2}6+\frac{z^4}{36}+\ldots\right)=\frac1z+\frac z6+\ldots$$

The above is the beginning of the Laurent series, just as you got. We usually are interested only in the first few terms: enough to know the multiplicity of the pole and the residue of the function there.

For $\;z=\pi\;$ you can do as above *around* $\;\pi\;$ using $\;\sin(z-\pi)=-\sin z\;$ (observe that then we get residue $\;-1\;$ , as expected...)