# Find coefficients of Laurentseries

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I find myself struggling a bit with Laurent series, and I'm currently stuck on this exercise below.

I want to find the coefficients $c_{-1}, c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3$ of the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ valid in $A(0,0,\pi)$.

My solution so far:

1. Investigate area, and find what singularities we have.

$A(0,0,\pi)$ gives that we have $-\pi,0,\pi$ as singularities.

2. Write as a Laurent series.

$$\sin(z)= z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}+O(z^7) \\\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sin(z)} = \frac{1}{z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}+O(z^7)} \\ = \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}+O(z^6)} \\ = \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1-(\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}+O(z^6)}$$

$$ \frac{1}{z}\sum_0^{\infty} \Big(\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}+O(z^6)\Big)^k$$

I would guesss that the next step is to somehow write out the sum again to find each coefficients, but I'm kind of lost at this point.

Would anyone like to give me a hint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the Laurent series for $\frac1{\sin(z)}$ in the regions $0&lt;|z|&lt;\pi$ and $\pi&lt;|z|&lt;2\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237289/how-to-find-the-laurent-series-for-frac1-sinz-in-the-regions-0z-pi)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, since it does not explain explicitly how they find the coefficients. It just gives me the answer, which I already know from the course literature that I got this exercise from.

Comment: Why don't you continue your calculation, like in [DonAntonio's answer in the proposed duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2237408)? I you only need the coefficients up to $c_3,$ simply expand
$$\sum_{k=0}^2\left(\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}\right)^k$$

Comment: Well, this is the part that I have trouble understanding and therefore question asked...:) Why do you only put the sum to $k=2$? And how do you know when you have "enough terms" that it will give you your answer? Because to me, i would probably have put a term higher than $z^4$ inside the paranthesis aswell, which makes the computation a lot more difficult.

Comment: For $k\ge3,$ $\frac1z\left(\frac{z^2}6+O(z^2)\right)^k=O(z^5)$ only contributes to the $c_i$'s for $i\ge5.$ And for $k\le2,$ the terms up to $z^4$ are sufficient inside the $k$-th power if you only need the coefficients of the sum up to the degree $4.$

Comment: But that does not give me any powers of $z^3$ does it?

Comment: Use the series of $\sin(z)$ and then the long division

Comment: Yes it does give you some $z^3$'s once you multiply your $z^4$'s by $\frac1z$ which stands in front of the sum.

Comment: Alright, thanks I now got the correct answer :)